# CORS issue with Lambda Function API created with Express.js and Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, aws-lambda, backend, serverless

I created a lambda function that holds the following code to have a Contact Me form on my portfolio site send me an email and autorespond. This is the code I have in lambda:

```
//our imports
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const path = require("path");
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
const serverless = require("serverless-http");

//handle url encoding
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true}));
//handle json payloads
app.use(express.json());
//app uses CORS functionality
app.use(cors());

app.get('/',(req,res) => {
    res.send("Hello world.");
});
//routing POST request from contact form
app.post('/', (req,res)=> {
    sendMail(req, res);
});

//integrate nodemailer to send mail with form data
//and send automated response
async function sendMail(req, res) {
    // configure transporter
    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
        port: 465,
        secure: true, // use SSL
        auth: {
            user: 'redacted',
            pass: 'redacted'
        }
    });

    //data to load email with
    const mailOptions = {
        from: req.body.email,
    to: "redacted",
    subject: "From: " + req.body.fName + " " + req.body.lName,
    text: "Sent from : " + req.body.email + "\n" + req.body.message, // plain text body
}

// Define and send message inside transporter.sendEmail() and await info about send from promise:
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error,info) => {
    if (error) {
        res.send('error');
    } else {
        console.log("Email Sent "+info.response);
        res.send("Email Sent");
    }
});

//lastly we send an automated response/
const automatedFields = {
    from: "redacted",
    to: req.body.email,
    subject: "Hey, it's redacted!",
    text: "THIS IS AN AUTOMATED RESPONSE\n\n" + 
    "Thank you for taking your time to look at my site and send me a message." +
    "I will get back to you as soon as possible."
}

transporter.sendMail(automatedFields, (error, info) => {
    if (error) {
        res.send('error');
    }   
    });}
module.exports.handler = serverless(app);
```

Everything works locally. I tested it within the test environment in lambda and it works there too. I used a Rest API to try and access it through my website's frontend. This is my frontend code that uses the API

```
try {
    let sendData = await fetch('apiurl(redacted)', {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type" : "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(formData),
    });

    const result = await sendData.text();
        alert(result);

    //clear up form incase another message
    fName.value = '';
    lName.value='';
    email.value='';
    message.value='';
}

catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
}
```

});

I have also made sure to go into my Rest API and ensure CORS is enabled from any origin. Why else wouldn't this work?

This is what I get in chrome

```
Access to fetch at 'redacted' from origin 
'redacted' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
 No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the 
 requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set 
 the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS 
 disabled.
```

Comment: What do you see if you access the URL directly... `curl -v -H "Origin: http://localhost" "https://apiurl/"`?

Comment: It connects fine. it returns a repsonse as well
{"statusCode":200,"headers":{"x-powered-by":"Express","access-control-allow-origin":"*","content-type":"text/html; charset=utf-8","content-length":"12","etag":"W/\"c-5E8zZAGdGKFRyrcHK1pAu1s+J08\""},"isBas

Comment: I've never seen curl output JSON for the headers. What did you actually use?

Comment: are you using API Gateway with Lambda, If yes can you share how did you configure CORS in API Gateway?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/PEjiAxC
this is the entire output
yes, i am using api gateway, this is how i configured cors:
default 4xx & 5xx checked on
methods: options checked on
Access-Control-Type-Headers: default setting, i'm assuming it handles almost everything
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '*'

Comment: There is check for GET also in enable CORS screen beside OPTIONS method, did you check it?